# Sharepoint Central Administration Ajax post to WebMethod return The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I've created an application page under _layouts folder with a single WebMethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string TestConnection(string server)
    {...}
```

and i was calling this method by posting an ajax request:

```
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteurl + "/_layouts/...",
            data: '{server: "' + server + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

and it was working just fine,
but the requirements changed so i had to change the location of the page from _layouts to _admin (Central Administration)
and update the ajax post url to the new one,
but now i'm getting the following error:

**The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.**

this seems to be something related to security but i cannot figure it out.

can anyone help!.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time of investigations and reading articles, i found that there is something called **SharePoint Form Digest** which is the responsible for security validation for SharePoint pages,
you can read more here:
http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2015/05/23/sharepoint-form-digest/

and here:
http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2012/06/sp2010-solving-the-mysteries-around-form-digest/

and to make my request valid i had to add the value of the "RequestDigest control" to the headers of the request like the following:

```
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                               "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                               "If-Match": "*"
               }
```